# I have a problem with an integral that I have already solved.

Tags: calculus

I have the integral

> $$\int \frac{e^t}{2+3 e^t+e^{2 t}} \, dt$$

However, when I integrate it I obtain $2$ results that are not equivalent but when I derive it I get to my initial expression, but I believe that the function is not multivalued.

> $$-2 \coth ^{-1}\left(2 e^t+3\right)$$

and

> $$\frac{\log \left(e^t \log (e)+\log (e)\right)-\log \left(e^t+2\right)}{\log (e)}$$

My doubt is why this happens, it is really a multivalued function or the results are equivalent and I don't realize it or it is another way of expressing the result.

Comment: They should be equivalent up to a constant. How did you arrive at the result? (Hint: Easiest is to factor and use partial fractions.)

Comment: $\ln e = 1$ ...

Comment: Multivalued? How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two antiderivatives are identical on the real line.

The second expression simplifies to $$\log \frac{e^t+1}{e^t+2}.$$  The first expression can be written in terms of logarithms by letting

$$y = \frac{1}{2} \coth^{-1} (2 e^t + 3), \tag{1}$$ from which it follows that

$$\coth \frac{y}{2} = 2e^t + 3. \tag{2}$$  Then recalling that $$\coth z = \frac{\cosh z}{\sinh z} = \frac{\frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{2}}{\frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}} = \frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{e^z - e^{-z}} = \frac{e^{2z} + 1}{e^{2z} - 1}, \tag{3}$$ we have $$e^y + 1 = (e^y - 1)(2e^t + 3). \tag{4}$$  Solving for $e^y$, we obtain
$$e^y = \frac{2e^t + 3 + 1}{2e^t + 3 - 1} = \frac{e^t + 2}{e^t + 1}. \tag{5}$$  Hence $$-y = -\log \frac{e^t + 2}{e^t + 1} = \log \frac{e^t + 1}{e^t + 2}, \tag{6}$$ which establishes equivalence.  They are not even differing by a constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

> $\frac{\log \left(e^t \log (e)+\log (e)\right)-\log \left(e^t+2\right)}{\log (e)}$

All of the $\log(e)$s can be replaced with 1.

> $\log \left(e^t + 1 \right) - \log \left(e^t+2\right)$

Combine logs:

> $\log \left(\frac{e^t + 1}{e^t+2}\right)$

This is *almost* arcoth. $\operatorname{arcoth} x = \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{x + 1}{x - 1}\right)$.

Let's rewrite your other expression:

> $-2 \operatorname{arcoth} \left(2 e^t+3\right)$

Substitute definition of arcoth:

> $-1 \log\left(\frac{2 e^t+4}{2e^t+2}\right)$

simplify internal fraction:

> $-1 \log\left(\frac{e^t+2}{e^t+1}\right)$

apply power:

> $\log\left(\frac{e^t+1}{e^t+2}\right)$

It's the same function expressed differently.